# Birthday problem: expected birthday collision "size"?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, birthday

Here's another formulation of a birthday problem: given $n$ people, and $m$ days, how to calculate the expected number of people having a birthday on any single **collision** day, i.e., a *day where two or more people have birthdays*?

UPD: to clarify: given a date, which is a birthday of at least two people (= collision date), what is the expected number of people who share this birthdate?

Comment: It is not clear what number you want the expected value of. Do you mean the _maximum_ number of people having the same birthday, the maximum being taken over all possible birthdays? The expected number for a randomly chosen day is easy to compute (and fairly small in typical examples): it is the number of days divided by the number of people. If you _only_ want to consider **collision** days (so an expected value would be expected to be at least $2$), then it is a problem that such days are not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @mck Are you asking for the average number of people who share a birthday (could be any day)? As in, if we tallied up the birthday frequencies, what is the average frequency among days that have $>1$ people?

Comment: no, I'm looking for expected number of people involved in a birthday "collision". I.e., given a date, which is a birthday of at least two people (= collision date), what is the expected number of people who share this birthdate?

Comment: @MarcusStuhr yep!

Comment: @mck As I said, the fact that such days do not always exist makes it problematic to assign a contribution to the expected value from such configurations. You could contribute the value $0$, or maybe $1$ (since some days do have $1$ person), but it is rather arbitrary to do that. Simply ignoring a part of your probability space is weird for expected values.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see what you mean, but this is exactly why I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Given $n\geq 2$ such "collision" days will exist with a non-zero probability, so the problem is still valid I guess... (and I'm not interested in days with 1 person).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using results in the related question [an earlier question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365713/birthday-problem-which-solution-for-expected-value-of-collisions-is-correct)

- The expected number of people who share a birthday with somebody else is $n-n\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1}$
- The expected number of days where two or more people have birthdays is $m - m \left(1-\frac1m\right)^n - n \left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1}$

and so dividing the first by the second may look like

$$\frac{n-n\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1} }{ m - m \left(1-\frac1m\right)^n - n \left(1-\frac1m\right)^{n-1} }$$

though note that this approach gives a greater weight to cases of distributions of people among more birthdays

As an example, with $m=2$ and $n=4$ this gives $\frac{28}{11}$.  If you consider the sixteen equally probable distributions of birthdays for four people among two days

```
Day1  Day2
ABCD  - 
ABC   D 
ABD   C
AB    CD
ACD   B
AC    BD
AD    BC
A     BCD
BCD   A
BC    AD
BD    AC
B     ACD
CD    AB
C     ABD
D     ABC
-     ABCD
```

there are $2$ cases of four people sharing a birthday, $8$ cases of three people sharing a birthday, $12$ cases of two people sharing (as well as $8$ of one and $2$ of zero) making the average number of people per shared birthday $\frac{2\times 4+8 \times3 +12\times 2}{2+8+12}=\frac{28}{11}$ as predicted.

A different approach could say the average should be calculated as the average of $2$ cases with the average being $4$, $8$ cases with the average being $3$ and $6$ cases with the average being $2$, giving a result of $\frac{2\times 4+8 \times3 +6\times 2}{2+8+6}=\frac{11}{4}$